# Show data from date 1 to date 2 specified by a particular user and then, get the sum of the data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP, MySQL project in which reporting section I want to show three functions of the database in the reporting section:

1. Fetch data from the database table `receipts`
2. Sum column `r_amount` by user
3. Filter data between two dates

Thanks

Comment: 3 functionality? Do you mean three database functions - what are they? I can *guess* based on your question, but it's not immiately clear (my guesses for two are: "filter on date range", "sum values" but I don't know what the third function is?)

Comment: No, there is only one database and 3 functionality means 1)data show 2) sum of a column. 3)show all above between date in one query

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT   user, SUM(r_amount)
FROM     receipts
WHERE    date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hello Welcome to Stack Overflow***

*You should search before posting anything, there are many threads/posts regarding this question*

```
select * from reciepts where date BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "'
order by id desc

select sum(r_amount) from reciepts where date BETWEEN '" . $from_date . "' AND  '" . $to_date . "' order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

1.data between 2 dates

```
SELECT items,... FROM receipts 
WHERE From_date >= 'date1'
AND To_date <= 'date2'
```

2.sum between 2 dates

```
SELECT sum(item)as r_amount FROM receipts 
WHERE From_date >= 'date1'
AND To_date <= 'date2'
```